# Saving Attachments from Access with Function and Query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a MS Access database where I have a public function and a query. I'd like the function to loop through every field in the 'Attachments' Column and then saves all attachments in that field. I need it to save with the "SEDOL" Column and corresponding row value as the first part of the file name, but it keeps bugging at the "Set rsA2 = fld2.Value" line in the code below. The SEDOL column is usual text field column The code works without the SEDOL saving name part. I'd love some suggestions on how to get it working. Thanks

```
Public Function SaveAttachments(strPath As String, Optional strPattern As String = "*.*") As Long

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset2
Dim rst2 As DAO.Recordset2
Dim rsA As DAO.Recordset2
Dim rsA2 As DAO.Recordset2
Dim fld As DAO.Field2
Dim fld2 As DAO.Field2
Dim strFullPath As String

'Get the database, recordset, and attachment field
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Core Securities")
Set fld = rst("Attachments")
Set fld2 = rst("SEDOL")
'Navigate through the table
Do While Not rst.EOF

'Get the recordset for the Attachments field
Set rsA = fld.Value
'BUGS IN NEXT LINE
Set rsA2 = fld2.Value
'Save all attachments in the field (works without rsA2)
Do While Not rsA.EOF
    If rsA("FileName") Like strPattern Then
        strFullPath = strPath & "\" & rsA2("SEDOL") & " - " & rsA("FileName")

    'Make sure the file does not exist and save
    If Dir(strFullPath) = "" Then
        rsA("FileData").SaveToFile strFullPath
    End If

    'Increment the number of files saved
    SaveAttachments = SaveAttachments + 1
    End If

    'Next attachment
    rsA.MoveNext
Loop
rsA.Close

'Next record
rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close
dbs.Close

Set fld = Nothing
Set rsA = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `SEDOL` column is just a string, you can't assign a recordset to it's value.

Just refer to it's value:

```vb
Public Function SaveAttachments(strPath As String, Optional strPattern As String = "*.*") As Long
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim rsA As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim strFullPath As String

'Get the database, recordset, and attachment field
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Core Securities")

'Navigate through the table
    Do While Not rst.EOF
'Get the recordset for the Attachments field
        Set rsA = rst("Attachments").Value
'Save all attachments in the field (works without rsA2)
        Do While Not rsA.EOF
            If rsA("FileName") Like strPattern Then
                strFullPath = strPath & "\" & rst("SEDOL").Value & " - " & rsA("FileName")      
'Make sure the file does not exist and save
                If Dir(strFullPath) = "" Then
                    rsA("FileData").SaveToFile strFullPath
                End If
'Increment the number of files saved
                SaveAttachments = SaveAttachments + 1
            End If
'Next attachment
            rsA.MoveNext
        Loop
        rsA.Close
'Next record
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

    rst.Close
    dbs.Close

    Set rsA = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing

End Function
```

I've also removed numerous strange things that were likely either unnecessary, or actively causing buggy behaviour